# Obtener datos de una cadena

Tags: javascript

¿Como puedo obtener todos y cada uno de los datos de una cadena? en Javascript, por ejemplo:

```
var cadena = "13msi2";
```

y mandar un alert con los valores de esa cadena por separado.

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con "obtener todos y cada uno de los datos de una cadena"? Realmente la cadena en sí ya puede ser un dato por sí solo.

Comment: A mandar en un alert por cada letra o número dentro de la cadena.

Comment: `var cadena = "13msi2";alert(cadena.split(""))`... Luego si quieres la información en binario necesitarías un conversor de caracter a binario.

Comment: He borrado mi respuesta porque sacaba todos los números juntos y las cadenas juntas por separado y no por cada valor que había en la cadena. No sé porque he entendido que querías los números y palabras que estuvieran agrupados por separado. Así evito confusiones. Un saludo :)

Comment: No te preocupes amigo, entiendo, si lo probé y efectivamente mostraba esos datos, quizá me expresé mal, y gracias por el aporte, seguramente puede servir mas adelante...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes:

1. Convertir el string a array
2. Hacer un ciclo for para recorrer el array
3. Enviar alert con cada valor del array

```js
var cadena = "13msi2";
    var cadenaSeparada = cadena.split("");
    for (i = 0; i < cadenaSeparada.length; i++) { 
     alert(cadenaSeparada[i]);
 }
```

Puedes revisar el ejemplo de w3schools:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Una pequeña modificación para tu ejemplo:
http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FAK7QL8SSNRF

Comment: Gracias !!!!!!!!! Justo lo que buscaba

Comment: De nada    :-).  Que bien que te pude ayudar.

Answer (score 1):

```
var cadena = "13msi2";
var cadenaSeparada = cadena.split("");
for (var i in cadenaSeparada) {
    document.write(cadenaSeparada[i]);
    document.write("<br/>");
}

// Output: 
// 1
// 3
// m
// s
// i
// 2
```

El método substr() devuelve los caracteres de una cadena que comienzan en una localización especificada y de acuerdo al número de caracteres que se especifiquen.

Ejemplo: Uso de substr

```
var cadena = "abcdefghij";

console.log("(1,2): "    + cadena.substr(1,2));   // '(1, 2): bc'
console.log("(-3,2): "   + cadena.substr(-3,2));  // '(-3, 2): hi'
console.log("(-3): "     + cadena.substr(-3));    // '(-3): hij'
console.log("(1): "      + cadena.substr(1));     // '(1): bcdefghij'
console.log("(-20, 2): " + cadena.substr(-20,2)); // '(-20, 2): ab'
console.log("(20, 2): "  + cadena.substr(20,2));  // '(20, 2): '
```

Este script muestra:

`(1,2): bc
(-3,2): hi
(-3): hij
(1): bcdefghij
(-20, 2): ab
(20, 2):`

Answer (score 0):

Si estas utilizando jQuery puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var cadena = "13msi2";
 var array = cadena.split("");

 $.each(array,function(i){
    alert(array[i]);
 });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```